# How can I switch the player Chrome is using to play flash games?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, flash, flash-player

there are several flash players installed on my system (old version of adobe flash player, adobe flash debugger, new grounds flash player). When I go on a flash game site Chrome player chooses the flash debugger to play the game. (In the past I managed to change this setting, now I forgot how I did this, or the Chrome options to do this have changed). How can I make Chrome to choose the old flash player or the new grounds flash player instead? I'm on a Windows 7.

Comment: The information contained in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1616858/offline-desktop-application-using-flash-stopped-working-today-12-jan-2021/1617039#1617039) question might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, Adobe has ended support for the Flash Player plugin. Flash content, including audio and video, will no longer play back in any version of Chrome.

Check your version info: chrome://version/

Users can manually switch to **ask first** before running Flash:

Scroll down to the `Privacy and Security section`, and click `Site Settings`. In Site Settings, scroll down to the Content and click Flash to open the options. To unblock Flash in Chrome, toggle the Block sites from running a Flash button to Ask first.

> You can manage how Flash playback happens using the
> DefaultPluginsSetting, PluginsAllowedforURLs, and
> PluginsBlockedForURLs policies. If these policies are not configured,
> for Chrome 76 and later, Flash playback is blocked by default.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7084871?hl=en#zippy=%2Coption-allow-chrome-to-manage-its-version-of-flash-player-recommended